# Intensity of Diffraction and inteferance

Tags: interference, diffraction

Why intensity of bands in diffraction decrease while moving away from central max  while that of interference do not?

Answer (score 1):

We will assume that the distance between centres of slits is several times greater than the width of each slit. The intensity of the interference pattern will then be 'modulated' by that of the diffraction pattern. In other words, the intensity of the bright fringes will be determined by the intensity of the underlying single slit diffraction pattern. So, for example, the interference fringes that are formed by the light of the first order diffraction beams will be less bright than those (more central fringes) within the zeroth order beams.

If you move only a little way from the central interference fringe, you may not notice any fall-off in intensity of interference maxima, because you may still be near the peak of the zeroth order diffraction beam. This non-effect will continue further out from the centre if the slits are very narrow. Can you see why?